# One model property is not being set when submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

Never had this problem before but it is happening on a single MVC action, all other model properties are being passed to the action method but ONE is omitted.

In the BilledItemViewModel model the property that exhibits the problem is declared as:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name="Factura")]
public int BillId { get; set; }
```

all other properties work fine but that one above does not.

The action method signature:

```
[HttpPost][ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddBillItem([Bind(Include = "BillId,ItemCodeId,Quantity,UnitPrice,Notes,TaxPercent,IsDebit,Description")] Models.BilledItemViewModel bitem)
```

The property is being displayed on the View as follows:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BillId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BillId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BillId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

When debugging I set a breakpoint on the action and it hits, it also says Model State IS valid. When I examine the values of the passed object (bitem) I can see all properties have the values I entered in the form EXCEPT BillId which is ZERO rather than ONE.

Comment: Can you also post cshtml part fort that property?

Comment: Just a guess, but are you including the `BillId` field as hidden in your cshtml? As @AdrianoRepetti indicated, this looks like a client -side binding problem

Comment: Just posted the CSHTML. Following @wahwahwah suggestion I removed the disabled="disabled" HTML attribute and when I eliminate that then the BillId is passed properly. I don't want the bill ID to be editable but I need it to be passed to the action so that I can associate the item to that bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your BillId is disabled in your view. Disabled fields are not sent to the server. Either just enable it for editing or make it a **hidden** input.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(h => h.BillId)
```

Hidden input will not be visible for users but will be sent to the server as well as the other fields from your form.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark it as readonly as well.

Readonly controls will be sent to server.